# How to compare a variable from CSV file with the JSON response to determine an assert case in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I am a beginner to jmeter, need some help for a situation. I have JSON response received from an endpoint, The response contains a user collection. I just want to loop on the user collection to match a value. If it matches then pass the assert case.

Response :

```
{
"company": {
    "data" : {
        "key": "SSL-121-TEST"
        "userResult": [
          {
            "id": "1001",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "status": [
              {
                "code":"1",
                "reason": "Not Submitted"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "1002",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "status": [
              {
                "code":"2",
                "reason": "No Result Found"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "1003",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "status": [
              {
                "code":"1",
                "reason": "Not Submitted"
              }
            ]
          }
      ]
    }
}
```

I am reading the **reason** from the csv file & want to compare with each userResult of the response. If any of the reason matches then assert case should pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).company.data.userResult.status.reason.collect { it -> it.get(0) }.contains(vars.get('reason'))) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Reason ' + vars.get('reason') + ' was not found in the response')
   }
   ```
3. That's it, if the value of the `reason` variable will not be found among "reasons" in the response - the request will be marked as failed.

More information:

- [Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)